# How to same element with unique XPath/CSS selector by both ID and Class?

Tags: python, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="btnCreditCard" class="paymentBtn bitcoin" style="display: none">
    <a class="button button-primary button-override has-icon-right" href="javascript:Biz.GlobalShopping.CheckOut.continueToReview(8);">
        <i class="button-icon-left"></i>Continue To Order Review<i class="button-icon-right fa fa-caret-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="btnMasterPass" class="paymentBtn masterpass" style="display: none;">
    <a href="javascript:Biz.GlobalShopping.CheckOut.continueToReview(4);" title="MasterPass" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img src="https://www.mastercard.com/mc_us/wallet/img/en/US/mcpp_wllt_btn_chk_147x034px.png" alt="MasterPass" />
    </a>
</div>

<div id="btnCreditCard" class="paymentBtn npa" style="display: none">
    <a class="button button-primary button-override has-icon-right" href="javascript:Biz.GlobalShopping.CheckOut.continueToReview(5);">
        <i class="button-icon-left"></i>Continue To Order Review<i class="button-icon-right fa fa-caret-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="btnCreditCard" class="paymentBtn billlater" style="display: none">
    <a class="button button-primary button-override has-icon-right" href="javascript:Biz.GlobalShopping.CheckOut.continueToReview(6);">
        <i class="button-icon-left"></i>Continue To Order Review<i class="button-icon-right fa fa-caret-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have to pick Anchor having parent DIV `<div id="btnCreditCard" class="paymentBtn billlater" style="display: none">`. The xPath I am currently using is `('//*[@id="btnCreditCard"]/a')`

Comment: you can also use `//div[contains(@class,'billlater')]/a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `and` in the XPath:

```
'//*[@id="btnCreditCard" and @class="paymentBtn billlater"]/a'
```